# Can I "re-enable" something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have disabled something and want to enable it again. Can I say that I "re-enable it" or do I simply "enable" it?

Comment: Go ahead and reenable it. It's not doing you any good the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was enabled at some point in the past, then you can re-enable it.

Technically if it was never enabled before and you turn it on for the first time, you shouldn't call that "re-enabling", but I doubt anybody would really care to split that hair if it's something that's likely to be flipped back and forth on any sort of frequent basis.

Comment: And then I can re-disable it.

Comment: You could "re-disable" it, but I doubt that most native speakers would use that term. We'd just say "disable" it. Because it's a toggle, most speakers would probably say "enable/disable" **in most contexts**. A Google search for "re-disable" shows only "re-enable/disable" in the first 100 hits. NGRAM viewer shows no BrE or AmE hits between 1800 & 2008.

Comment: Nobody will split that hair. I've refrigerated many things that have never been frigerated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz frigerate/refrigerate is completely different ...no analogy here:  Frigerate is obsolete; refrigerate does not mean re-frigerate - it comes from the noun refrigerator.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple toggle switch, I would employ either **enable, restore** or **reinstate.**

When dealing with a trigger device that would not come on immediately, I would rather use **arm** or **rearm**.